# Using react-hot-loader with custom babel preset

Tags: babeljs, react-hot-loader

My app doesn't support older browsers, and I like to trim down the set of Babel transforms to make the code easier to debug (so that the code in the debugger looks like more the original source).

However, when I migrate to react-hot-loader 3, this no longer works. That is, I can get RHL 3 to work with the standard es2015 preset, but not with my custom set of transforms. What happens is that the react components are rendered but never mounted, and won't respond to any events.

The set of transforms I am trying to use is:

```
var babel_plugins = [
  'transform-runtime',
  'transform-object-rest-spread',
  // Transforms needed for modern browsers only
  'babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants',
  'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping',
  'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-function-name',
  'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters',
  'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring',
  // No longer needed with Webpack 2
  // 'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs',
  'react-hot-loader/babel',
];
```

In response to the comments, here's more information:

Here's how I'm using the AppContainer:

```
export default (
  <AppContainer>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
     (My routes here...)
    </Router>
  </AppContainer>
);
```

And here's my dev server setup:

```
// Adjust the config for hot reloading.
config.entry = {
  main: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8000', // WebpackDevServer host and port
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', // "only" prevents reload on syntax errors
    './src/main.js', // Your appʼs entry point
  ],
  frame: './src/frame_main.js', // Entry point for popup tab
};
config.plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());

const compiler = webpack(config);
const server = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
  contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, '../builds/'),
  historyApiFallback: true,
  stats: 'errors-only',
  hot: true,
});
server.listen(8000, '127.0.0.1', () => {});
```

Here's the relevant portion of my webpack config:

```
test: /\.jsx?$/,
include: __dirname + '/src',
exclude: __dirname + '/src/libs',
use: [
  {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      plugins: babel_plugins,
      presets: babel_presets
    },
  },
  {
    loader: 'eslint-loader',
  },
]
```

Comment: Can you share the code how you mounted RHL 3? Without that, can't help.

Comment: Updated the original posting, let me know if any additional info would be helpful.

Comment: The same problem happens when I try to use 'babel-preset-modern-browsers'.